# Qt StyleSheet custom style attribute custom QGLwidget

Tags: css, qt, opengl, qt4, pyqt

I have created a subclass of QGLwidget and I was hoping that I could use a stylesheet to tell openGL how to render a scene.

For Example:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("CustomWidget { background-color: yellow }");
```

Then in my paintGL method:

```
QColor bg = "Get 'background-color' style somehow"

glClearColorf(bg.redF(), bg.greenF(), bg.blueF(), 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

Also, is it possible to create custom style sheet attributes?

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("CustomWidget { foo-attr: 1 }");
```

I have read up on the QStyle and QStyleOption classes, but I don't quite understand how to apply them to a practical application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare Q_PROPERTY in your custom widget and then set them with

```
CustomWidget
{
    qproperty-yourPropertyName: "value";
}
```

You can access BG of your custom widget with QPalette

```
QColor bg = palette().color(QPalette::Window);
```

But I'm not sure if it will work

Comment: Thanks. This works great. btw `background_color  = palette().color(QPalette::Window)`